# Is there a way to avoid zeroing vector elements on resize, for the sake of performance?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, stdvector

Is there any way to make `std::vector` faster on `reserving + resizing`?

*I would like to achieve the performance which would be somewhat equivalent to plain C arrays.*

**See the following code snippets:**

```
TEST(test, vector1) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
      std::vector<int> a;
      a.reserve(10000000);
      a.resize(10000000);
   }
}

TEST(test, vector2) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
      std::vector<int> a(10000000);
   }
}

TEST(test, carray) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
      int* new_a = new int[10000000];
      delete[] new_a;
   }
}
```

First two tests are two times slower (`4095 ms vs 2101 ms`) and, obviously, that happens because `std::vector` is nulling the elements in it. *Any ideas on how this could be avoided?*

Or probably there is some standard *(boost?)* container that implements a fixed-size and heap-based array?

Comment: In order for the tests to do the same amount of work, the `carray` test needs a `for(std::size_t idx=0; idx<10000000; ++idx) new_a[idx]=0;` in there. Once that's in, I doubt you'll find significant changes.

Comment: I suggest using a profiler and only if the performance is low optimize. The above code is not probably present in a normal application. You wouldn't do such things normally.
Probably the best way is to create your own array class to have more control.

Comment: @Iulian: This is one of those comments for which I want to be able to down-vote comments. Why on earth would you want to create your own array? Have you actually tried to implement `std::vector`? You'll find that this is surprisingly hard to come up with a veryion that's both correct and fast.

Comment: @sbi Such "benchmarks" are irrelevant in my opinion. This is why one must test on real application rather then making such kind of benchmarks - it will probably result that performance is **OK** event with the "slow" std::vector. If he finds performance problems in these places then he can think of rewriting parts used from the std::vector to waste less CPU cycles. Furthermore I believe that the code above is unlikely yo exist in a **real** application. My principle is first make it work, then make it better/faster.

Comment: @lulian: which is a good principle. however @sbi is totally on the mark here. The stl is a well thoughtout, well designed library that (if used properly) will yield performance nearly as good as their bothersome C counterparts. Creating your own array class will result in more time spent debugging than it would have possibly saved over the lifetime of the codebase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well naturally the first 2 tests are slower.  They explicitly go through the entire vector and call "int()" on each element. Edit:  This has the effect of setting all the elements to "0".

Just try reserving.

There is some very relevant info to your question in this question i asked a while back:

[std::vector reserve() and push_back() is faster than resize() and array index, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461276/stdvector-reserve-and-push-back-is-faster-than-resize-and-array-index-wh)

Comment: Correct, the `carray` version isn't doing the *exact* same thing as the vector counteparts. std::vector<T>::reserve() is the answer here

Answer (score 2):

There's [boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/array.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's stack based, and, for example, you can't even allocate a huge array of 1 million ints without changing the stack size.

Comment: A `std::auto_ptr<boost::array<int>>` would do the job.

Comment: @HardCoder1986: If you want an heap-based array, `std::vector` is what you want. Fix your test and you will see that it is exactly as fast as manually fiddling with dynamically allocated C arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Were your tests performed in debug or release mode?  I know the microsoft compiler adds a lot of debug checks that can really slow down performance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a [boost::scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm), but if this really is that performance critical, maybe you should try putting the initialization/allocation outside the innermost loop somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you've already done some profiling and determined the use of vector in this fashion to be a hotspot. If not, it's a bit premature to consider the differences unless you're working at a very tight, small-scale application where every clock cycle counts in which case it's even easier to use a profiler and there's just as much of a reason to do so.

boost::scoped_array is one solution. There's no way to get vector to not initialize the elements it stores. Another one is std::deque if you don't need a contiguous memory block. deque can be significantly faster than vector or a dynamically-allocated array with the same number of elements as it creates as it creates smaller memory blocks which operating systems tend to deal with better along with being cache-friendly.